# Exiting\ returning to the main function - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a code in matlab, in this code I have a function `f()` that calls the function `g()` that calls the function `h()`.

Function `f()` calls `g()` in a `for` loop that iterates 101 times, and `g()` calls `h()`.
Each iteration, `h()` displays an image, the user does some changes to the image until he presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the <kbd>O</kbd> keys:

- If he presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> `h()` returns a file of the changes he made, and continues to the next image.
- If he presses <kbd>O</kbd> then `h()` returns the file of the changes. but doesn't continue to the next images, instead, it returns to `Main`.

Its like `exit(1)` in C.

Any ideas how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`return`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/return.html). Though it won't return you immediately to h, you'll have to put `return` in g somewhere as well.

As long as you name  at least one output variable in the [function declaration](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/function.html), the output will be returned no matter whether you use `return` or not.

For example:

```
function out = f()
    % do stuff
    x = g();
    % do stuff with x
end


function out = g()
    % do other stuff
    out = h();
    if strcmp(out, 'O') % check whether user entered 'O' in h()
        return;
    else
        % do different stuff
    end
end

function out = h()
    out = input();
end
```

Comment: @Junaxx thanks alot for answering. Sorry my question wasn't clear, but h() must return some input even if the user pressed "O". In other words, f() calls g() for i=0 to 100 (times), and g() calls h(). For each i, h() displays an image, the user does some changes to the image till he press "Enter" or "O". If he pressed enter h() return a file of the changes he made, and contintue to the next image. if he pressed "O" then h() returns the file of the changes, but doesn't continue to the next images, it returns to Main. Any ideas now?. and thanks again.

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh: Ah, I see. In that case you can let `h()` return multiple output variables, like `function [img, key] = h()`. It will still return to `g()` first, I don't think there's a way around that. But based on the value of `key`, `g()` can continue or break its loop.

Comment: @Junaxx. Thanks! I may use your solution after all, but I have to do some changes first. For now I checked if the user pressed "O", if so I created a file named: "Exit". then I checked in f() if the file exist, if so I "returned" to main. Thanks again !